# Index out of bounds for datagridview with object collection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Ultranewbie here on vbnet.

So had a problem on a simple code, but i cannot figure out why.

I have a datagridview on a form, a list of objects defined in the form and i use it as datasource.
So, wanted to have the columns present on form load so did this:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim l As New List(Of Entities.Product)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = l
    End Sub

End class
```

And it works.

After that i load the objects in the list and assign it as datasource:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each r As DataRow In d.Tables("table").Rows

        Dim p As New Entities.Product
        p.ID = r.Item("id")
        p.name = r.Item("name")
        p.prize = r.Item("prize")

        l.Add(p)

    Next

    Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = l

End Sub
```

Everything works as expected.... until I click on a line in the Datagridview.
Then I get this:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Index -1 does not have a value.
```

I don't have any code handling the click yet... It is like if it lost the references to the bound collection.

I found that if i remove the lines in the Load event i don't have the issue....

Anyone can explain why this happens? Is this a bug?

If I assign the datasource to nothing and then reassign it should reload, regardless of where it was assigned before right?

Thanks for your input guys.

Daniel

Comment: why do you move the data from a datatable to a List?

Comment: Ah, it's just an assignment thay gave us. They wanted us to do it like that.

Comment: If this answers the question, please click the checkmark so it is removed from the Unanaswered list.

Answer (score 0):

The generic `List(Of T)` is suboptimal as a `DataSource` if/when that data can change.

#### Option 0

The `DataTable` originally containing the data would make a perfectly functional `DataSource`.  I am not sure what the point is of copying the data to a typed List is.

#### Option 1 - BindingList(Of T)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

' NVP is a simple Name-Value pairs class
Private NamePairs As BindingList(Of NVP)

    Private Sub FormLoad(....
        NamePairs = New BindingList(Of NVP)
        
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dgv.DataSource = NamePairs
        ...
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(...
        NamePairs.Add(New NVP("ziggy", 42))
        NamePairs.Add(New NVP("zacky", 11))
        NamePairs.Add(New NVP("zoey", 2))
    End Sub
```

With no further heroics on your part, the additions to the list automatically show in the DGV:

[image]

Note that this only monitors changes to the list *contents* not the list *items*.  If you change the `Name` or `Value` of one of the objects, the change will not automatically show up.  That would require the Type (class) to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When properties change, the `BindingList` will relay the changes to the control it is bound to.

#### Option 2 - BindingSource

You can get the same result using a `BindingSource` with one extra step.

```
Private NamePairs As List(Of NVP)
Private BSPairs As BindingSource

Sub FormLoad.....
    NamePairs = New List(Of NVP)
    BSPairs = New BindingSource(NamePairs, Nothing)

    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dgv.DataSource = BSPairs
End Sub
```

Adding to the list in a click event:

```
NamePairs.Add(New NVP("ziggy", 42))
NamePairs.Add(New NVP("zacky", 11))
NamePairs.Add(New NVP("zoey", 2))

BSPairs.ResetBindings(False)
```